# Create taxonomy with meta term using the WP Rest Api

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, rest-api, term-meta

I am trying to create taxonomy elements (the taxonomies are already registered) from the front end using the REST Api v2. I am able to do so except not able to save the meta fields from the taxonomies.

---

I have a registered taxonomy ("place") and I am trying to create elements for it using the Rest Api.

The taxonomy has a term meta ("my_meta"). I am able to get the information from the taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'slug_register_meta' );
function slug_register_meta() {
    register_rest_field( 'place',
        'meta', 
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'slug_get_meta',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}
function slug_get_meta( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_term_meta( $object[ 'id' ] );
}
```

which lets me get the information when I access: /wp-json/wp/v2/place/53

```
{
    "id": 53,
    "count": 0,
    ...
    "taxonomy": "place",
    "meta": {
        "my_meta": [
            "the meta value"
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

I can register a new taxonomy element through JavaScript:

```
var place_new = new wp.api.models.Place({
    name: 'the name',// works
    description: 'the description',// works

    my_meta: 'test1',// doesn't work

    fields: {// doesn't work
        my_meta: 'test3'
    },

    meta: {// doesn't work
        my_meta: 'test2'
    }

    });

place_new.save();
```

**The problem is the my_meta value won't save**, I am not sure how to refer to it or if there is some PHP I am missing.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @input No, it was for a side project. If I come back to it I would probably try [MB Term Meta](https://metabox.io/plugins/mb-term-meta/), [MB REST API](https://metabox.io/plugins/mb-rest-api/) if I dont find the way.

Comment: Posted an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50397449/1654250 if you're interested

Comment: This worked for my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/62490342/441016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need an `update_callback` in `register_rest_field()`. Please note that I haven't tested this.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'slug_register_meta' );
function slug_register_meta() {
    register_rest_field( 'place',
        'meta', 
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'slug_get_meta',
            'update_callback' => 'slug_update_meta',
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}
function slug_get_meta( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_term_meta( $object[ 'id' ] );
}
function slug_update_meta($value, $object, $field_name){
    // please note: make sure that $object is indeed and object or array
    return update_post_meta($object['id'], $field_name, $value);
}
```

Comment: @alvaro, did it works for u ? I'm facing the same problem, but this doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your meta value as an array to your meta key.

```
var place_new = new wp.api.models.Place({
    name: 'the name',// works
    description: 'the description',// works

    meta: {
        "my_meta": [
            "new_meta_value"
        ]
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working.

Comment: I've updated it, I'm on mobile now and would confirm once I'm at my desk

Comment: The edit is giving a JavaScript error "Unexpected token .", the dot is not accepted.